# Magento Custom Option

Tags: magento-1.7, custom-options, image-preview

I am using file uploading for image upload in magento.

If customer giving order and upload image for engrave product where can i get image which uploaded by customer. or how can i able to print or download it ?

Comment: Custom option used for this purpose

Comment: eagerly waiting for you because not getting proper answer in any ware google order giving image link but its redirect me on dashboard not able to view or download.

Comment: There are not getting answer but its only edited my question.